# stuck in the middle of a command line

Tags: zsh

machine: Macbook Pro mid-2014 Catalina terminal

I probabbly did something wrong but now I got stuck in the middle of a command (maybe) and can not execute anything.[image]line. Any idea how to return to the starting position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prompt change from `.... %`   to `dquote` , so you inside a string , so if you type `"` , your are going back to the shell .

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+C terminates any command
Otherwise closing & reopening Terminal works :)